# Kotlin: Need to proguard Kotlin Data Class?

Tags: proguard, kotlin, android-proguard, data-class

I have a data class defined as below

```
package com.mypackage.model

object Model {
    data class News(val photo: String, val title: String, val description: String)
}
```

When I compile it using Proguard (i.e. release build), the data I received and store in the model all becomes null. They are still there i.e. ArrayList listOfNews does have the expected retrieved size. However all their content is null.

Debug build this is okay. To solve this, I use this proguard rules, and it resolve the problem.

```
-keep class com.mypackage.model.** { *; }
```

Is this expected? i.e. all Data Class should be pro-guarded?

Comment: Do you get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` or `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`? If not it's most likely not Proguard's fault in your case.

Comment: Didn't really get anything. It just silently run and my program still works. But the data are null. Perhaps I need to scan through the log messages.

Comment: Check through the log, not seeing any of such messages. Given that this is a release build, all debug log is not shown perhaps. If I change to debug build, then this error no longer exhibit, so no trace of issue in debug build.

Comment: How exactly are you storing data in your model? Are you using reflection?

Answer (score 1):

as far as I can tell, that behavior is expected. It might be related to them being serializable or so. I also have to add the model classes to proguard.